# Checking the type of parameter entered into a function

Tags: python

So I want to create a function and have it perform differently based on the type of the parameter passed in. Specifically I want it to do one thing if a string is entered, and something else if a list is entered. Is this possible in Python? And if so how would I go about doing it?

At the moment I've tried using isinstance() but it doesn't seem to be hitting any of my if statements:

```
def tester(*args):
    if (isinstance(args, str)):
        return "String"
    elif (isinstance(args, list)):
        return"List"
    else:
        return "You dun goofed"
```

EDIT: The user will only ever be passing in one argument at a time, either a list or a string.

Comment: `*args` will *always* return a tuple.

Comment: Ah thanks, is there another way to do what I'm trying to do?

Comment: Is the function going to accept one parameter? Or can the user enter more?

Comment: The parentheses around the if/elif conditions are not required in Python and therefore somewhat untypical. The else-branch should raise a TypeError exception instead of returning a special value diffult to recognize as such for the caller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like all you would be passing is a single argument to your function. In that case remove the '*' since it is always considered as a tuple of arguments. It is **variable-length arguments** and is to be used when you aren't sure of the number of arguments that you function would need.

```
def tester(args):
    if (isinstance(args, str)):
        return "String"
    elif (isinstance(args, list)):
        return"List"
    else:
        return "You dun goofed"
```

If your function actually requires variable length parameters and you want to check whether the first parameter being passed is a string or a list, you can do:

```
def tester(*args):
    if (isinstance(args[0], str)):
        return "String"
    elif (isinstance(args[0], list)):
        return"List"
    else:
        return "You dun goofed"
```

Comment: This helped me understand things a lot better, thank you very much :)

Answer (score 3):

`*args` is the **tuple** of arguments passed to the argument. The splat (`*`) operator unpacks the arguments given in the function call eg.

```
>>> def tester(*args):
        print args
        print type(args)


>>> tester(1, 'a')
(1, 'a')
<type 'tuple'>
```

So what you probably want to do is check `isinstance` on each of the args and make sure they are all `str` or `list` for example:

```
if all(isinstance(a, str) for a in args):
```